# combinations proof - stuck on the algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

prove that $k(^{n}_{k})= n(^{n-1}_{k-1})$
What I have so far:
I'm trying to use pascals rule and the definition of combinations to expand this algebraically but I keep getting tied up in the algebra. 
$$k(^{n}_{k})= n(^{n-1}_{k-1})$$ 
The RHS expands to $\frac {n(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-2)!}$ and this is what I need to get to
Now the LHS  $$k(^{n}_{k})= k[(^{n-1}_{k})+(^{n-1}_{k-1})]$$
$$=k(^{n-1}_{k})+k(^{n-1}_{k-1})$$
$$=(\frac{k(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!})+(\frac{k(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-2)!})$$
this is where I get stuck, I can't get my common denominators and make it work out.
this is what I tried:
$$\frac{k(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-2)!(n-k-1)k}+\frac{k(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-2)!}$$ 
but multiplying k(n-k-1) across to get common denominators isn't seeming to get me anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k>0$$$\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k!)}=n\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{k\cdot (k-1)!\cdot [(n-1)-(k-1)]!}$$

$$\implies \binom nk=\frac nk \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: well then... I was definitely making that a lot more complicated than necessary

Answer (score 1):

Here is a combinatorical proof:

Consider a committee of $k$ people, with a chairman, to be chosen from a group of $n$ people.

- We can select $k$ people, in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, and then choose a chairman from the $k$ people. Our number of ways is $$k\binom{n}{k}$$
- We can select the chairman first from $n$ people, and then choose $k-1$ members from $n-1$ people.

$$n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Thus these two numbers are equal,